# PHP redirect outside of Iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe, parent-child

Greeting!

I have a webpage with a Iframe in it. The Iframe is from a third party app that the user can use. once the user finishes the application and tells the Iframe application that they are complete, they press the submit button. Once the submit button is pressed, it redirects them to a page on my site, but they still inside the Iframe.

My question is - Is there a way to force the page they are redirected to redirect the PARENT page of the Iframe? I have encountered several session/cookie issues that force the user to relog into the Iframe, thus causing a endless wave of Iframes. If I could simply simple tell Iframelanding.php to redirect its parent page to myaccount.php I would not have the compatibility issues.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could try this on your iframe landing page, it will redirect the parent iframe but they have to be in the same domain.

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

Comment: Worked like a char. Thank you Carlos!

Answer (score 3):

consider using this in your  :

```
<head>
  <base target="_parent" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function(){
   var isInIframe = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false; 
   if(isInIframe == true){ //redirect if iframe
        window.top.location.href = "http://gmail.com/";
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.